# Firebase v9 React JS IndexOf is not a function

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

for some reason it is throwing me an error in the console "TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function" and I do not understand very well why it happens. I am using Firestore and Firebase v9 Modular and basically it is a function that creates a category in firestore database and also inside the category creates a test task.

Here is the full error:

```
TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function
    at Function.fromString (index.esm2017.js:1032)
    at va (index.esm2017.js:14990)
    at App.jsx:48
```

And the line 48 in the error message is:

```
const taskRef = doc(collection(db, "categorias"), where("uid", "==", currentUser), newDocRef.id)
```

Here is my code :)

```
const currentUser = '1234'

const crearCategoria = useCallback(async() => {
    try {
      const newDocRef = doc(collection(db, "categorias"));

      await setDoc(newDocRef, {
        name: categoryName,
        uid: currentUser,
        projectId: newDocRef.id
      })

      const taskRef = doc(collection(db, "categorias"), where("uid", "==", currentUser), newDocRef.id)
      await setDoc(taskRef, {
       name: 'prueba',
       uid: currentUser,
       projectId: newDocRef.id
    })

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
    }
  })
```

Comment: What are you trying to do? It seems you are updating documents where("uid", "==", currentUser) which is not possible. You need references to those documents first.

Comment: I was experiencing this same "TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function" error with Firestore v9, and I came across this question while trying to figure it out. Sharing feedback for others that find this in the future: I love Firestore and Firebase, but sometimes it is difficult to figure out what an error message is telling you. In this case, "TypeError: n.indexOf is not a function" means you have an invalid doc reference. The correct way to fix it for this particular example is in Frank's answer below, but more generally, if you see this error you need to figure out why your doc ref is wrong.

Comment: -most200. Thanks! this was the case for me! I realized I was doc referencing the user directly rather than the user.uid (my document name)

Answer (score 4):

As Dharmaraj commented, you cannot perform an update on a query. You'll instead have to:

1. Execute the query to find the matching document(s).
2. Loop over the documents in your application code.
3. Update each of them in turn.

In code that should be something like:

```
const taskQuery = doc(collection(db, "categorias"), where("uid", "==", currentUser))
const taskDocs = await getDocs(taskQuery)
taskDocs.forEach((taskDoc) => {
  await setDoc(taskDoc.ref, {
    name: 'prueba',
    uid: currentUser,
    projectId: newDocRef.id
  })
})
```